# Not able to pack hex bytes into unsigned char array or pointer properly

Tags: c, struct, hex

I tried to imitate a struct with a unsigned char array or pointer, but I am not able to obtain the same hex values.

.input is correct with print().
I am trying to get the same effect from stringBytes_Data or data_hexStrFormatted with print().

Can anyone advise?

Given

```
struct _vector {
char *input;
unsigned char len;
};


static struct _vector tv2 = {
   .input = "\x6b\xc1\xbe\xe2\x2e\x40\x9f\x96"
            "\xe9\x3d\x7e\x11\x73\x93\x17\x2a"
            "\xae\x2d\x8a\x57\x1e\x03\xac\x9c"
            "\x9e\xb7\x6f\xac\x45\xaf\x8e\x51"
            "\x30\xc8\x1c\x46\xa3\x5c\xe4\x11"
            "\xe5\xfb\xc1\x19\x1a\x0a\x52\xef"
            "\xf6\x9f\x24\x45\xdf\x4f\x9b\x17"
            "\xad\x2b\x41\x7b\xe6\x6c\x37\x10",
   .len = 64,
};
```

And function to view the data:

```
static void print(char *intro_message, unsigned char *text_addr,
                    unsigned int size) {
unsigned int   i;

for (i = 0;  i < size;  i++) {
    printf("%2x ", text_addr[i]);
    if ((i & 0xf) == 0xf)
        printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
}
```

How may I get the same effect with:

```
char* stringBytes_Data = "6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172aae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e5130c81c46a35ce411e5fbc1191a0a52eff69f2445df4f9b17ad2b417be66c3710";
```

I tried, but the result is wrong :

```
unsigned char* data_hexStrFormatted;

int lengthOfStr = strlen(stringBytes_Data);
int charCounterForNewStr = 0;       
int formattedLength = (2*lengthOfStr)+1;

data_hexStrFormatted = (unsigned char*) malloc((formattedLength)*sizeof(unsigned char)); // x2 as we add \x to XX, and 1 for NULL end char


for(i=0; i<lengthOfStr; i=i+2) { 
      // prepend \x
         data_hexStrFormatted[charCounterForNewStr++] = '\\';
         data_hexStrFormatted[charCounterForNewStr++] = 'x';

      data_hexStrFormatted[charCounterForNewStr++] = stringBytes_Data[i]; 
      data_hexStrFormatted[charCounterForNewStr++] = stringBytes_Data[i+1];
} 
data_hexStrFormatted[formattedLength-1] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", data_hexStrFormatted);
printf("%d byte length \n", strlen(data_hexStrFormatted)/4);

 print("data_hexStrFormatted",
                    (unsigned char *)
                    data_hexStrFormatted,
                    (formattedLength)/4);
```

Comment: The conversion between `"\xAB"` and the character with hex value `AB` is something that your compiler does - there's no runtime equivalent. You've got to write code specifically to do the conversion, as the answeres suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking:

- Given a string containing pairs of hex digits, convert the hex digits to byte values?

If so, then code similar to the following can be used:

```
static inline int hexit(const unsigned char c)
{
    static const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    return strchr(hex_digits, toupper(c)) - hex_digits;
}
```

This function works correctly for valid hex digits; it will produce nonsense for invalid inputs.  If you decide you need to detect erroneous input, you'll need to improve it.  There are other ways to write this function (lots of them, in fact).  One that can be effective is an array of 256 bytes statically initialized with the correct values, so you simply write `return hex_array[c];`.

```
char* stringBytes_Data = "6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172aae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e5130c81c46a35ce411e5fbc1191a0a52eff69f2445df4f9b17ad2b417be66c3710";

size_t len = strlen(stringBytes_Data);
char buffer[len / 2];

assert(len % 2 == 0);

for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
    buffer[i / 2] = hexit(stringBytes_Data[i]) << 4 | hexit(stringBytes_Data[i+1]);

printf("%.*s\n", (int)len/2, buffer);
```

This code sets the array `buffer` to contain the converted code.  It won't work correctly if there's an odd number of characters in the array (that's what the assertion states).

---

#### Working code - #2

Using the `print()` function from the question with the `info_message` argument removed since it is unused:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Vector
{
    char *input;
    unsigned char len;
};

static struct Vector tv2 =
{
    .input = "\x6b\xc1\xbe\xe2\x2e\x40\x9f\x96"
             "\xe9\x3d\x7e\x11\x73\x93\x17\x2a"
             "\xae\x2d\x8a\x57\x1e\x03\xac\x9c"
             "\x9e\xb7\x6f\xac\x45\xaf\x8e\x51"
             "\x30\xc8\x1c\x46\xa3\x5c\xe4\x11"
             "\xe5\xfb\xc1\x19\x1a\x0a\x52\xef"
             "\xf6\x9f\x24\x45\xdf\x4f\x9b\x17"
             "\xad\x2b\x41\x7b\xe6\x6c\x37\x10",
    .len = 64,
};

static inline int hexit(const unsigned char c)
{
    static const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    return strchr(hex_digits, toupper(c)) - hex_digits;
}

static void print(unsigned char *text_addr, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%2x ", text_addr[i]);
        if ((i & 0xf) == 0xf)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static void print2(const char *tag, const unsigned char *data, size_t size)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%2x ", data[i]);
        if ((i & 0x0F) == 0x0F)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static void print_text(const char *tag, const char *data, size_t datalen)
{
    char buffer[datalen / 2];

    assert(datalen % 2 == 0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < datalen; i += 2)
        buffer[i / 2] = hexit(data[i]) << 4 | hexit(data[i + 1]);

    //printf("%s: [[%.*s]]\n", tag, (int)datalen / 2, buffer);
    assert(memcmp(buffer, tv2.input, tv2.len) == 0);
    print((unsigned char *)buffer, datalen / 2);
    print2(tag, (unsigned char *)buffer, datalen / 2);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *stringBytes_Data =
        "6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a"
        "ae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e51"
        "30c81c46a35ce411e5fbc1191a0a52ef"
        "f69f2445df4f9b17ad2b417be66c3710"
    ;

    print_text("buffer", stringBytes_Data, strlen(stringBytes_Data));
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
6b c1 be e2 2e 40 9f 96 e9 3d 7e 11 73 93 17 2a 
ae 2d 8a 57 1e  3 ac 9c 9e b7 6f ac 45 af 8e 51 
30 c8 1c 46 a3 5c e4 11 e5 fb c1 19 1a  a 52 ef 
f6 9f 24 45 df 4f 9b 17 ad 2b 41 7b e6 6c 37 10 

buffer:
6b c1 be e2 2e 40 9f 96 e9 3d 7e 11 73 93 17 2a 
ae 2d 8a 57 1e  3 ac 9c 9e b7 6f ac 45 af 8e 51 
30 c8 1c 46 a3 5c e4 11 e5 fb c1 19 1a  a 52 ef 
f6 9f 24 45 df 4f 9b 17 ad 2b 41 7b e6 6c 37 10
```

#### Working code - #1

Redone — previous versions had various 'off by a factor of two' errors which were partially concealed by the system zeroing a buffer.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Vector
{
    char *input;
    unsigned char len;
};

static struct Vector tv2 =
{
    .input = "\x6b\xc1\xbe\xe2\x2e\x40\x9f\x96"
             "\xe9\x3d\x7e\x11\x73\x93\x17\x2a"
             "\xae\x2d\x8a\x57\x1e\x03\xac\x9c"
             "\x9e\xb7\x6f\xac\x45\xaf\x8e\x51"
             "\x30\xc8\x1c\x46\xa3\x5c\xe4\x11"
             "\xe5\xfb\xc1\x19\x1a\x0a\x52\xef"
             "\xf6\x9f\x24\x45\xdf\x4f\x9b\x17"
             "\xad\x2b\x41\x7b\xe6\x6c\x37\x10",
    .len = 64,
};

static inline int hexit(const unsigned char c)
{
    static const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    return strchr(hex_digits, toupper(c)) - hex_digits;
}

static void print(const char *tag, const unsigned char *data, size_t size)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%2x ", data[i]);
        if ((i & 0x0F) == 0x0F)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static void print_text(const char *tag, const char *data, size_t datalen)
{
    char buffer[datalen / 2];

    assert(datalen % 2 == 0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < datalen; i += 2)
        buffer[i / 2] = hexit(data[i]) << 4 | hexit(data[i + 1]);

    printf("%s: [[%.*s]]\n", tag, (int)datalen / 2, buffer);
    assert(memcmp(buffer, tv2.input, tv2.len) == 0);
    print(tag, (unsigned char *)buffer, datalen / 2);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *stringBytes_Data =
        "6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a"
        "ae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e51"
        "30c81c46a35ce411e5fbc1191a0a52ef"
        "f69f2445df4f9b17ad2b417be66c3710"
    ;

    print_text("buffer", stringBytes_Data, strlen(stringBytes_Data));
    return 0;
}
```

Raw output on a UTF-8 terminal (it isn't valid UTF-8 data, hence the question marks):

```
buffer: [[k???.@???=~s?*?-?W????o?E??Q0?F?\????
R???$E?O??+A{?l7]]
buffer:
6b c1 be e2 2e 40 9f 96 e9 3d 7e 11 73 93 17 2a 
ae 2d 8a 57 1e  3 ac 9c 9e b7 6f ac 45 af 8e 51 
30 c8 1c 46 a3 5c e4 11 e5 fb c1 19 1a  a 52 ef 
f6 9f 24 45 df 4f 9b 17 ad 2b 41 7b e6 6c 37 10
```

Raw output converted into UTF-8 as if it was ISO 8859-15 (or 8859-1):

```
buffer: [[kÁŸâ.@é=~s*®-W¬·o¬E¯Q0ÈF£\äåûÁ
Rïö$EßO­+A{æl7]]
buffer:
6b c1 be e2 2e 40 9f 96 e9 3d 7e 11 73 93 17 2a 
ae 2d 8a 57 1e  3 ac 9c 9e b7 6f ac 45 af 8e 51 
30 c8 1c 46 a3 5c e4 11 e5 fb c1 19 1a  a 52 ef 
f6 9f 24 45 df 4f 9b 17 ad 2b 41 7b e6 6c 37 10
```

The data doesn't seem to have any particular meaning, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: I may not be able to use assert() on my system.


If you do this

print_text("buffer",
      (unsigned char *)
      buffer,
      len); 

Only the 1st 32 bytes are right. You are close. Very close.

Comment: Can you give an alternative to that?
If the print shows the same contents, it should be solved.

Comment: The `assert` does not have to be present; you could ignore the possibility, or drop the odd character, or return without doing anything, or return an error condition, or anything else you choose to handle the error.  Fixing `hexit()` to report erroneous hex would be fiddlier; you'd have to change its interface, or the way you use it.

Comment: I dropped the assert();, but given the input, it's not showing the full right values.

Comment: Are you telling me that the code in the working example section is misbehaving?  It looks like it is working correctly to me.  I added a check inside `print_text()` to verify that the converted data in `buffer` is identical to the data in your `tv2` structure, and indeed it was.  The test was: `assert(memcmp(buffer, tv2.input, tv2.len) == 0);`

Comment: It's showing

6b c1 be e2 2e 40 9f 96 e9 3d 7e 11 73 93 17 2a
ae 2d 8a 57 1e  3 ac 9c 9e b7 6f ac 45 af 8e 51
31 40 40  0 ae  0  0  0 bf 40 40  0 d5 8c  9 77
3f fc f6 ec  2  0  0  0 c4 40 40  0 8a 17 40  0

The last 32 bytes are not correct.

Comment: The print() has to be the same as the one I use.
I can't use assert();

Comment: What compiler are you using, on which platform?  Are you sure you're using the fixed code?  I'm testing with GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks.

Comment: I'm running DevCpp now, however I'll also be testing with Eclipse CDT later.

Comment: OK; the core code is unchanged, but I'd got a bug in the `printf()` statement.  I've incorporated your `print()` function, with renamed variables and printing the 'tag' (`info_message`) since the compiler options I use don't allow unused variables.  I think it is now producing the correct answer.  The hex dump is longer and the second half isn't very useful, but it is still there for completeness (and to make sense of the first output).

Comment: Could you use my print()?

ie.

print(char *intro_message, unsigned char *text_addr,
                    unsigned int size);

Comment: Not unless you fix it to use `intro_message`.  I don't post code that doesn't use all the arguments to the functions.  Fix that, and I'll use your print instead of mine, though the variable names are too long and the types aren't what I'd use.

Comment: we can remove `intro_message`, but the last 32 bytes is still incorrect.

Comment: 6b c1 be e2 2e 40 9f 96 e9 3d 7e 11 73 93 17 2a
ae 2d 8a 57 1e  3 ac 9c 9e b7 6f ac 45 af 8e 51
`31 40 40  0 ae  0  0  0 c8 40 40  0 d5 8c  9 77
88 ad 2e c0  2  0  0  0 cc 40 40  0 1f 18 40  0`

Comment: I found it, 

`int len = strlen(stringBytes_Data);`, not `int len = strlen(stringBytes_Data)/2;`

Comment: Hmmm…I removed that divide by two quite a few minutes ago.

Comment: Excellent, @Jonathan Leffler.